# Download a file with AngularJS + FileSaver.js + .Net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, download, filesaver.js

I'm trying to download an file what can be pdf, cvs, word, jpg or png. To do this, I'm using angularjs + [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). don't know why but, my downloads are always corrupted.

Someone can help me ?

> Note:
>   midia.Nome - Name of my file. 
>   midia.Tipo - The type of the file.
>   midia.Path - Physical path on project. 
>   midia.MidiaBytesString - Bytes
>   on Base64 to convert to blob.

```
<a href="{{midia.path}}" target="_blank" ng-click="Download(midia.MidiaBytesString, midia.Nome, midia.Tipo)">Download</a> <br />
```

My File download method:

```
$scope.Download = function(bytes,nome,tipo){
var file = new File([bytes], nome , {type: "application/octet-stream"});
saveAs(file);
};
```

My View Model

public class MidiaViewModel
    {
        public int MidiaId { get; set; }

```
    public string MidiaDescricao { get; set; }

    //public string MidiaPath { get; set; }

    public byte[] MidiaBytes { get; set; }

    public string MidiaBytesString { get; set; }

    public int OsId { get; set; }

    public virtual OsViewModel Os { get; set; }

    public string MidiaNome { get; set; }

    public string MidiaType { get; set; }

    public string MidiaPath { get; set; }

    public long MidiaSize { get; set; }
}
```

My register Midia:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AtualizarMidias(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> arquivos, IEnumerable<string> descricoes, int osId)
{
    var ordermDeServico = _osService.ObterPorIdLazyLoad(osId);

    foreach (var file in arquivos)
    {

        string targetFolder = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/");
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.FileName);


        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var itens = arquivos.ToList();
            var des = descricoes.ToList();
            var index = itens.FindIndex(c => c.FileName == file.FileName);
            var midiaViewModel = new MidiaViewModel
            {
                MidiaType = file.ContentType,
                MidiaNome = file.FileName,
                MidiaPath = targetPath,
                MidiaSize = file.ContentLength,
                MidiaDescricao = des[index].ToString(),
                MidiaBytes = converterArquivo(file)
            };

            var midia = Mapper.Map<MidiaViewModel, Midia>(midiaViewModel);
            midia.OsId = ordermDeServico.OSId;
            file.SaveAs(targetPath);
            _midiaService.Salvar(midia);
        }
    }

    return Json(new { resultado = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And where i make the call to my angular $scope:

```
[HttpPost]
public string getMidiasOS(int idOS)
{
    var getMidias = _midiaService.ObterMidiaPorIdOs(idOS);
    List<MidiaAngularViewModel> midiaNova = new List<MidiaAngularViewModel>();


    foreach (var midia in getMidias)
    {

        midiaNova.Add(new MidiaAngularViewModel
        {
            Id = midia.MidiaId,
            Path = midia.MidiaPath,
            Tipo = midia.MidiaType,
            Descricao = midia.MidiaDescricao,
            MidiaBytesString = Convert.ToBase64String(midia.MidiaBytes),
            Nome = midia.MidiaNome
        });
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(midiaNova);
}
```

**EDIT**

Guys, I solved my problem using the Ameni topic in the follow link: [download file using angularJS and asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216283/download-file-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc)

All I need to do was create like the Post method on the Ameni topic and the download by path function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add/use the `download` attribute and you will be fine. More about download attribute can be found at [w3c download documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

```
<a href="{{midia.path}}" download="filename">Download</a>
```

Comment: This approach give me network error when file is downloaded.

Comment: @FábioCarvalho Looks like there a an error in your filestream on your backend side. The Download attribute is working well. You should be able to access your file link by directly past it into your browser.

Comment: I update my question, can you look at it ? I dont know what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: @FábioCarvalho You have to return a filestream, not a Json object. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api if you return a nice file on the URL the download will work very well.

Comment: Thank you Lin, I solved my problem looking this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003050/failed-network-error-while-downloading-the-files-from-google-chrome  ^^